# Changes getting made in two different pieces of code - JQuery

Tags: jquery, input, autofill

Here are 2 input tags where "id1" tag can be modified but "id2" can't, so when I make any changes in the "id1" tag the value is changing in the "id2" tag but the value in "msg" class is not changing as the value of "id2" tag is changing automatically without typing there anything by our own, I tried `.change` , `input propertychange` but it is not working.
Requesting your inputs

```
<div class="wrap">
<input id= "id1"></input>
<input id = "id2" readonly></input>
<div class="msg"></div>
</div>
<script>
   $('#id1').bind('input propertychange', function() {
      $('#id2').val($(this).val());
   });
   $('#id2').bind('input propertychange ', function() {
      $('.msg').html($(this).val());
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

trigger the event .. I can't imagine why you need to do that but

```js
$('#id1').bind('input', function() {
  $('#id2').val($(this).val()).trigger('input');
});
$('#id2').bind('input', function() {
  $('.msg').html($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
<input id= "id1"></input>
<input id = "id2" readonly></input>
<div class="msg"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're totally welcome @bhardwaj_g .. Have a great day :-)

Comment: but this is not the problem the problem is bigger

Comment: @bhardwaj_g  what the problem is??